# progress bar with async task in android

Tags: android

i am new to android.so any body know how to display the progress bar for certain amount of time and then again invisible it.i had created one progress bar in the xml file and i had some  millisecond so to display the progressbar for that amount of time.any kind of example and want to do all the progresstask with asynctask Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/.
Must be useful to you.

Comment: this thing will make the background invisible for sometime not applicable i want to use my defined progressbar on xml,thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`onProgressUpdate(Integer...)`** method of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

FYI, by using **`publishProgress()`** method inside `doInBackground()`, you can perform UI update operation. So you can update progress bar as and when you want from `doInBackground()` method.